# Yii2 use of html helper class?

Tags: yii2

In forum i see this is not yii2 standard `<?= $var ?>` .
Yii2 standard code is `<?= Html::encode($var) ?>`.
Anyone know use of Yii2 html helper class?

Answer (score 3):

The content of  `<?= $var ?>` , tipically is not encoded automatically by yii2 so  the values of the $var  will be HTML-encoded using

```
 Html::encode($var).
```

For a useful guide about HtmlHelpers you can see this doc

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html

and this ref ..

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-html.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html

Yii2 provide a useful set of Html helpers for a easy code manipulation

l